# Stack Overflow theme

Tags: discussion, design

The new MSE banner & logo is beautiful...Are there any plans to update the Stack Overflow design at any point to fit in with the roundedness of the other sites?

[image: Meta banner]

I really like the rounded cleanliness on the other sites, as opposed to Stack Overflow's blockiness:

[image: Rounded tags]

Roundedness and blockiness were the best words I could come up with to describe the UI :)

Comment: I was actually going to point out that MSE is broken because it has too much colour for a meta site.

Comment: For those interested, [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) just got a design makeover.

Comment: @John of course they would...

Comment: @PeterMortensen Is it really necessary to edit old posts just to rename SO?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not, well, not any time in the near future anyway. If you take a look at the meta sites for all of the trilogy sites (Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault) - you'll notice that they're basically the same and this is quite intentional.

What *has* been kicked around a bit is the idea of updating the 'beta blue' theme that new beta (and child meta) sites inherit, but that's pretty much all it has been, kicking the idea around.

I don't think we'd be downright *opposed* to giving the trilogy meta design some love, but it's not really high on the priority list, at least for now.

But, who knows - Jin might just get inspired and then magic happens, but he's got to have time for that too :)

Comment: Can you please make everything full-width? I hate this tiny strip down the middle of my huge expensive monitor.

Comment: @bjb568 The TeX community loves talking about the readability of wide margins (which I agree with), but something should definitely be done. Maybe left justifying with smart use of two-column, like putting edit boxes in the second column and preview in the first?

Comment: @bjb568 I do not think the question/answer pane should be any wider, as Trevor mentioned wide texts are not very readable. But since everyone is getting wide screens these days, SE can make use of screen real estate and make Hot Network Questions a separate column.